# Python regex to remove all words which contains number

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a Python regex which allows me to remove all worlds of a string containing a number.

For example:

```
in = "ABCD abcd AB55 55CD A55D 5555"
out = "ABCD abcd"
```

The regex for delete number is trivial:

```
print(re.sub(r'[1-9]','','Paris a55a b55 55c 555 aaa'))
```

But I don't know how to delete the entire word and not just the number.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do you need a regex? You can do something like

```
>>> words = "ABCD abcd AB55 55CD A55D 5555"
>>> ' '.join(s for s in words.split() if not any(c.isdigit() for c in s))
'ABCD abcd'
```

If you really want to use regex, you can try `\w*\d\w*`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\w*\d\w*', '', words).strip()
'ABCD abcd'
```

Comment: euuh no I do not need really a regex, I don't know why I am fixed on it ^^<br>
Your 2 answers works fine so Thanks you very much :)

Comment: This regex approach is only working if there are alphabets with numbers but not with symbols, eg: www.abcd-79.com; for that use `re.sub("\S*\d\S*", '', words).strip()` instead

Answer (score 14):

Here's my approach:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "ABCD abcd AB55 55CD A55D 5555"
>>> re.sub("\S*\d\S*", "", s).strip()
'ABCD abcd'
>>>
```

Comment: I know this post is old, but could you tell me why it doesn't works when I do \S*\d*\S*? I mean take eg ABC555DEF, here there are multiple digits, but still \d matches all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The below code of snippet removes the words mixed with digits only

```
string='1i am20 years old, weight is in between 65-70 kg  '

string=re.sub(r"[A-Za-z]+\d+|\d+[A-Za-z]+",'',string).strip()

print(s)
```

OUTPUT: `years old and weight is in between 65-70 kg name`

Comment: You should make use of formatting to improve your answer.