# How to remove words containing numbers in a data frame column in python

Tags: python, pandas

My data is given as:

```
NCC3           concat_data
1          ALP0_2019_08 Purch. of 1 laptop Mk Assis,47000
2          ALP0_2019_29 11 HP EBook x3601030&DS for staff
```

The output should be:

```
NCC3           concat_data
1        Purch. of laptop Mk Assis
2         HP EBook for staff
```

Comment: Please post the code you wrote so far... we're not gonna write code for you

Comment: Ideally, the question poster should show some effort taken to resolve the issue. Currently, it is lacking. Hence the downvote.

Comment: If I were you, I would first think of solving the issue for one line at a time. If so, then the problem reduces to having the right `regex` for the task.

Once such a function is defined, all you need to do is to use the `apply` function in pandas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082130/python-regex-to-remove-all-words-which-contains-number

Answer (score 3):

The following should do:

```
df['concat_data'] = df.concat_data.str.replace(r'\w*\d\w*','')

print(df)
                    concat_data
0   Purch. of  laptop Mk Assis,
1        HP EBook &DS for staff
```

If in the above case, `Assis,47000` should be considered a single word due to the absence of a space, instead use:

```
df['concat_data'] = df.concat_data.str.replace(r'\S*\d\S*','')

print(df)
              concat_data
0   Purch. of  laptop Mk 
1     HP EBook  for staff

​
```

Setup -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'concat_data':['ALP0_2019_08 Purch. of 1 laptop Mk Assis,47000', 
                                  'ALP0_2019_29 11 HP EBook x3601030&DS for staff']})
```